# Targeting last item in foreach loop problem

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to target the last item in a foreach loop but it's acting a little strange.

I've got two items in the loop, I've tried the following:

1. Not set a +/- for the count, this targets the first item.
2. Using -1 as the count also targets the first item.
3. Using +1 as the count doesn't target any items until you add a 3rd
   item, then it works as intended.

Here's the code, can anyone help?

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));
foreach($pages as $key => $post)
{
setup_postdata($post);
$fields = get_fields();
?>

<div class="event<?php if( $key == (count( $pages ) +1) ) echo 'last'; ?>">             
</div>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
<?php 
$pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order'));

// keep a record of the number of pages -1
// in order to compare against 0 indexed array key
$pagesNo = count($pages)-1;

foreach($pages as $key => $post)
{
setup_postdata($post);
$fields = get_fields();
?>
<div class="event<?php if( $key == $pagesNo ) echo 'last'; ?>"></div>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I've edited my question to make more sense! When using -1 it targets the first item rather than the second one.

Comment: @Rob: Can you add a `var_dump($pages)` before the loop and edit your question to share the output? If the array is 0 indexed, you definitely need to subtract -1 from the count of array.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to count, a `for` or `while` loop might be a better than `foreach`.